# Deserialize two separate objects from one XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am serializing two objects to XML and writing to two separate XML files, then merging the two files to one file. What I want to do is be able to deserialize each object separately from the merged file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <ArrayOfMapItem>
    <MapItem>
      <EpgId xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">0000DAC2-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</EpgId>
      <MapId xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">5D195A5B-FBBF-4042-8AB3-E4558CA1D347</MapId>
      <ServiceCollectionId xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">657A62F8-260A-482B-BC86-7D6DEA9D8984</ServiceCollectionId>
      <ServiceCollectionName xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">Rich_Gold</ServiceCollectionName>
      <Services xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">Rich_Gold</Services>
      <TunerPosition xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">1</TunerPosition>
    </MapItem>
    <MapItem>
      <EpgId xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">000010FA-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</EpgId>
      <MapId xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">5DF26284-D0EA-4071-9DA0-22E463314D65</MapId>
      <ServiceCollectionId xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">83CFD40E-C7FB-420D-B9FC-5E5B711B9E74</ServiceCollectionId>
      <ServiceCollectionName xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">G-D9154-DF8-01_SC</ServiceCollectionName>
      <Services xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">G-D9154-DF8-PIP-01, G-D9154-DF8-FS-01</Services>
      <TunerPosition xmlns="Company.Domain.Name.Space">2</TunerPosition>
    </MapItem>
  <ArrayOfMapItem>
  <ArrayOfArrayOfGrant>
    <ArrayOfGrant>
      <Grant ResourceId="5df26284-d0ea-4071-9da0-22e463314d65" PrincipalExternalId="roman" PrincipalType="Group" ResType="Package" Right="Record">
        <Conditions xmlns="http://www.company.com/egtv/bss">
          <TimeExpiration Start="2014-05-01T07:00:00" End="9999-12-31T23:59:59.997" Type="TimeExpiration" Expiration="9999-12-31T23:59:59" />
        </Conditions>
      </Grant>
      <Grant ResourceId="5df26284-d0ea-4071-9da0-22e463314d65" PrincipalExternalId="PETSIN" PrincipalType="Group" ResType="Package" Right="Record">
        <Conditions xmlns="http://www.company.com/egtv/bss">
          <TimeExpiration Start="2014-04-04T18:52:24.867" End="9999-12-31T23:59:59.997" Type="TimeExpiration" Expiration="9999-12-31T23:59:59" />
        </Conditions>
      </Grant>
      <Grant ResourceId="5df26284-d0ea-4071-9da0-22e463314d65" PrincipalExternalId="PETSIN" PrincipalType="Group" ResType="Package" Right="Record">
        <Conditions xmlns="http://www.company.com/egtv/bss">
          <TimeExpiration Start="2014-04-04T18:53:28.797" End="9999-12-31T23:59:59.997" Type="TimeExpiration" Expiration="9999-12-31T23:59:59" />
        </Conditions>
      </Grant>
      <Grant ResourceId="5df26284-d0ea-4071-9da0-22e463314d65" PrincipalExternalId="PETSIN" PrincipalType="Group" ResType="Package" Right="Record">
        <Conditions xmlns="http://www.company.com/egtv/bss">
          <TimeExpiration Start="2014-04-04T19:17:42.983" End="9999-12-31T23:59:59.997" Type="TimeExpiration" Expiration="9999-12-31T23:59:59" />
        </Conditions>
      </Grant>
    </ArrayOfGrant>
    <ArrayOfGrant>
      <Grant ResourceId="6f26ecfd-4bfe-4c5d-af0b-164a93f448e8" PrincipalExternalId="roman" PrincipalType="Group" ResType="Package" Right="Record">
        <Conditions xmlns="http://www.company.com/egtv/bss">
          <TimeExpiration Start="2014-05-01T07:00:00" End="9999-12-31T23:59:59.997" Type="TimeExpiration" Expiration="9999-12-31T23:59:59" />
        </Conditions>
      </Grant>
    </ArrayOfGrant>
  </ArrayOfArrayOfGrant>
</root>
```

I have tried this:

```
    XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MapItem[]), new XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfMapItem"));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataMerged.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        MapItem[] r;
        r = (MapItem[]) mySerializer.Deserialize(fs);
    .....
    }
```

But when the code gets to “mySerializer.Deserialize” it get:

```
InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=<root xmlns=''> was not expected.
       Source=Microsoft.GeneratedCode
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderChannelMapItemArray.Read3_ArrayOfChannelMapItem()
```

Is there a way I can deserialize the objects individually from one merged file? When I deserialize the objects while they are still in separate files I have no problems.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide

Comment: `deserialize each object separately` <--- do you mean you want to deserialize an XML element into a corresponding `MapItem` object?

Comment: You can try couple of things, implement IXmlSerializer and ignore root element. Or you can create a wrapper class Root with two properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to load the XML into an [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), pick out each section, and deserialize each one individually using your existing serialization code.

First, some extension methods:

```
public static class XObjectExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XElement element)
    {
        return element.Deserialize<T>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)));
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XElement element, XmlSerializer serial)
    {
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            object result = serial.Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Then, do:

```
        var xml = GetXml(); // Load the XML.  (In my test code it's just a string literal.)
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // In your case, you would use XDocument.Load(filename)

        var mapXml = doc.Root.Element("ArrayOfMapItem");
        var grantXml = doc.Root.Element("ArrayOfArrayOfGrant");

        if (mapXml != null)
        {
            var mapItems = mapXml.Deserialize<MapItem[]>();
            Debug.WriteLine(mapItems.GetXml()); // Two items deserialized successfully.
        }

        if (grantXml != null)
        {
            var grantItems = grantXml.Deserialize<Grant[][]>();
            Debug.WriteLine(grantItems.GetXml()); // Two arrays of arrays deserialized successfully.
        }
```

For testing purposes, I used the following abbreviated versions of your classes:

```
[XmlType("MapItem", Namespace="")]
public class MapItem
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace="Company.Domain.Name.Space")]
    public string EpgId { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Grant", Namespace="")]
public class Grant
{
    [XmlAttribute("ResourceId")]
    public string ResourceId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("PrincipalExternalId")]
    public string PrincipalExternalId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple, straight forward and easily done! And thank you for responding so quickly!!